# How do I access triple nested values in JSON using Java?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to access the "text" values in the below JSON and create an ArrayList with those values.  How would I approach that?  I am trying to use com.fasterxml.jackson.

```
{
    "searchApiFormatVersion": "1.0",
    "searchName": "SalaryAccessRole",
    "description": "",
    "totalRowCount": "2",
    "returnedRowCount": "2",
    "startingReturnedRowNumber": "1",
    "basetype": "Person",
    "columnCount": "1",
    "columnHeaders": [
        {
            "text": "EMPLID",
            "dataType": "string"
        }
    ],
    "resultSet": {
        "rows": [
            {
                "values": [
                    {
                        "text": "2270127",
                        "dataType": "string",
                        "columnHeader": "EMPLID"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "values": [
                    {
                        "text": "1050518",
                        "dataType": "string",
                        "columnHeader": "EMPLID"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I've used this to success for the searchName but am trying to get the text under resultSet->rows->values->text.

```
JsonNode salaryExcludePersonNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(sourceJson);
String person = salaryExcludePersonNode.get("searchName").textValue();//this works
String person2 = salaryExcludePersonNode.get("resultSet")
                .get("rows")
                .get("values")
                .get("text")
                .textValue());//this says that com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode.get(String)  is null
```

Comment: "rows" is an array, so you probably want `.get("resultSet").get("rows").get(0).get...`. Same for "values".

Comment: String person2 = salaryExcludePersonNode.get("resultSet")
                .get("rows")
                .get("values")
Here, get("rows") returns an array,  need `get("rows").get(0).get("values")....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you tagged this question as a Jackson question, but I think JSONPath may be a good fit here.

The JSONPath library is available as a Maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

For the JSON in your question, all of the "text" values can be selected using a single JSONPath selector:

```
$.resultSet.rows..text
```

`$` - start at the root of the JSON.

`.resultSet.rows` - navigate to the `rows` array.

`..text` - recursively find all `text` entries.

The results are automatically added to a Java `List`:

```java
String jsonAsString = "{...}";
List<String> textList = JsonPath.read(jsonAsString, "$.resultSet.rows..text");
```

You can also read from a `java.io.File` directly:

```java
File jsonFile = "/your/path/to/file.json";
List<String> textList = JsonPath.read(jsonFile, "$.resultSet.rows..text");
```

The list will be populated with 2 entries:

```
2270127
1050518
```

---

References:

[JSONPath syntax overview](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#readme)

[JavaDocs](https://javadoc.io/static/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/2.7.0/index.html?com/jayway/jsonpath/JsonPath.html)